How to install virtualenv on ubuntu 24.04?
I have been freshly installing a ubuntu 24.04 VM on a windows 10 host and I have problems to install virtualenv. I run the command
sudo pip3 install virtualenv

and get the error
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.12/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.

In the error it says to use a virtual environment, which is exactly as I am trying to do! So I cannot install a virtualenv because I do not have a virtualenv. That does not make any sense!
However I tried also, as suggested:
sudo apt install python3-virtualenv

(which did not install anything) and then:
python3 -m venv myenv

with the following output:
Error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'lib' -> '/home/alex/Work/Repos/pypdzug/myenv/lib64'

So how to install virtualenv safely without breaking my fresh ubuntu 24.04 installation right away? And why is that so very complicated and cumbersome?
Maybe there is a website detailing the process in detail on how to install/setup the most basic stuff with a new ubuntu VM?
Maybe it is related to the folder I want to try to create the VM which is a shared folder with the windows host? When I do ls -l I see permissions like
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf

Maybe I cannot create a virtual env on a shared folder?
When I try to create a folder on the actual filesystem inside the VM then it works.
Maybe there is a way to "fix" the permissions(?) or something so I can also create virtual environments on the shared file system?

How did you install 24.04?  Because I can create virtualenvs without any issue on 24.04 using the standard mechanisms - sudo apt install python3-virtualenv && python3 -m venv myvenv - without issue on 24.04.  did you make any modifications to your 24.04 system in terms of permissions, etc. ?

Please take a look at my question. Because you CAN NOT just create a virtualenv as I get the error I mentioned in my question above! And no, I did not make any modifications to the permissions to my system ...

Ah the issue might be related to the file system where I try to create the virtual env which is a shared file system with the windows host ...

is this on a WSL setup?  If that's the case then yes this will not work.  If this is a VM or such that has a shared fileshare to the host then also, yes, that may not work because that's not actually mounting as a mechanism because it's not really a "linux" filesystem at that point.  You need to have your venvs local to your VM / linux, not on the Host.  (Also, yes, this is a "system modification" because you've mounted a shared storage)
